# Javascript regex get the number part from a specific word

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

Say that we have an element with these classes: "floatLeft item4".

If I want to save the number "4" to a variable from "item4" how would i do that?

I think I would use this pattern "/item(\d+)/" but do I use replace or match and how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use match like this:

```
var str = "item4",
    num = +str.match(/item(\d+)/)[1]; // => 4
```

I used unary `+` to cast to a number. You can use `parseInt` or `Number` constructor instead.

Answer (score 2):

```
var str = "item4",
    num = (str.match(/item([0-9]+)/)||[])[1]; // if no match, `match` will return null therefore the `|| []` (or empty array). 

console.log(num); // "4" (typeof num === "string")

console.log(+num) // 4 (typeof num === "number")
```

Answer (score 2):

using replace:

`"floatLeft item4".replace(/.*item(\d+)/,"$1")`

using match:

`"floatLeft item4".match(/item(\d+)/)[1]`

exec (alot like match)

`/item(\d+)/.exec("floatLeft item4")[1]`

using split (again, alot like match):

`"floatLeft item4".split(/item(\d+)/)[1]`

http://jsfiddle.net/UQBNn/

though the `split` method is not supported in all browsers (like IE..)

Comment: You shouldn't split with regex in <=IE8

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `.match(..)` with a capture group.

```
"floatLeft item4".match(/item(\d+)/)
// Result: ["item4", "4"]
```